What do name:delim and name:hook do in biblatex?
The name:delim are name:hook macros seem low-level and each take only one argument that is normally a combination of nameparts. And yet Moewe takes care to combine them in different ways.
Here's a standard name display scheme in biblatex.def
\newbibmacro*{name:family}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \mkbibcompletenamefamily{%
       \ifdefvoid{#3}
         {}
         {\ifcapital
            {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
            {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
          \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
       \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibcompletenamefamily{%
       \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot}}}%

Here are his custom solutions for displaying Ethiopian names
\newbibmacro*{name:ethiopian}[3]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1#2#3}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1#2#3}%
  \mkbibethgiven{#1}%
  \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibethpat{#2}\isdot}%
  \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibethpap{#3}\isdot}}

and CJK names
\newbibmacro*{name:cjk}[3]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#3#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#3#1}%
  \mkbibnamefamily{#1}%
  \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}}%
  \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamecjk{#3}}}

There's obviously a pattern, but I don't see they affect the visible output. So I want to know how much attention should I pay to this as I try to cobble together a custom name display of my own.
From biblatex.def:
\newbibmacro*{name:hook}[1]{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\lbx@initnamehook{#1}}
    {}}


\newbibmacro*{name:delim}[1]{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststart}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
       or
       test \ifmorenames
     }
       {\printdelim{multinamedelim}}
       {\lbx@finalnamedelim{#1}}}
    {}}


@cfr moewe's solutions in their entirety make a difference, of course, but I didn't think the invocations of the two macros of interest do. And according to his answer below, they indeed make no difference in English.

@cfr No, you missed the point. Even when you're applying Moewe's solutions to Ethiopian entries (or CJK ones), you name:delim and name:hook would not produce any difference so long as you're using biblatex in the English language. See Moewe's answer below.

@cfr It's okay that you didn't understand my question and probably think that I'm an idiot. (Hint: the question is not about name:ethiopian but rather name:delim.) What's important is Moewe understood it perfectly and gave a helpful answer. I'll just quote his answer here and leave it at that: "Unless you use a language in which one needs to modify words depending on what follows (and that modification is implemented by biblatex) you won't notice a difference in your name formats when you don't feed the arguments in 'the right order'."

I understand, believe me. But I didn't mean to start a war over it.

@cfr Okay I couldn't help myself.  name:ethiopian makes a difference, of course, when used correctly but the arguments fed  name:delim and name:hook to don't in English. You could replace #1#2#3 in Moewe's code with blah and it still wouldn't matter, and that that's what I wanted to know.

name:delim typesets the delimiter between different names. Usually (multinamedelim) this is a comma or some such boring punctuation, but the last delimiter can be special (finalnamedelim), e.g. sometimes it is an "and". In some languages the finalnamedelim ("and") may change its form depending on the word/name that follows (in Spanish you have to switch between "y" and "e"). That's why name:delim gets fed some information about the name so it can decide the form of the "and". Generally speaking the order of the arguments in the argument of name:delim should follow the order of the name parts as printed by the relevant bibmacro. (This was true for the Ethiopian case, but not for the CJK macro. I changed that in the linked post.)
name:hook has a similar role. But it applies only to the first name. It is relevant for things like edited by in French, where the by would be de or d' depending on the name.

Unless you use a language in which one needs to modify words depending on what follows (and that modification is implemented by biblatex) you won't notice a difference in your name formats when you don't feed the arguments in "the right order".
The general rule of thumb is that name:delim and name:hook should be fed the name part arguments in the same order in which they are printed by the macro.
